# Data Loader CLI - sporadically doesn't return results

Tags: data-loader

Anyone had an issue where when using the Data Loader CLI they won't get back any results? We have a scheduled job in the morning to export some data to a CSV. This has been running for about a week now and we have had only 1 successful scheduled run. As soon as I go into the scheduled job and run it again I get my data without issue.

I have tried changing the start time which is how I got the 1 successful run. 
I have the debug file option set to True and I do get logs but I don't see any error messages in the log.

I will sometimes either not get a file at all or I will get a blank file. 
I have the time out in the bean set to 1800 seconds, so 30 min. When I run the job by hand it completes in 1-2 minutes.

Anyone think of anything else I can try? Do I need to somehow warm up, cache, the database in the morning?

I am using VisualCron for scheduling and it is calling the batch file with the process.exe export command in it. I have no timeouts set in VisualCron.

Comment: It might be an issue with the environment. Have you tried adjusting the Data Loaders heap memory [outlined here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000170855&type=1)?

Comment: Interesting but I would think that I would hit this when I run it manually as well. The guide details out how to adjust shortcuts but not how to make these changes when using CLI. Would you added this to C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\bin\dataloader-39.0.0-java-home.exe?